# Receive and send mail using mailgun in thunderbird

Tags: email, mailgun, thunderbird

I would like to be able to receive and send mail from my custom domain in thunderbird. I've configured the DNS nameservers to point to cloudflare, and cloudflare has the MX & TXT records setup to use mailgun for sending and receiving mail. Mailgun forwards received mail to my gmail address. I've replace my custom domain name with customdomain.me

### Namecheap nameservers config (domain name provider)

```
bayan.ns.cloudflare.com
gene.ns.cloudflare.com
```

### Cloudflare DNS

```
Type  Name            Content            Proxy status
MX    customdomain.me mxb.mailgun.org 10
MX    customdomain.me mxa.mailgun.org 10
TXT   mailo_domainkey ...
TXT   customdomain.me v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all
CNAME email           mailgun.org        Proxied
```

### Mailgun config

```
catch_all() Priority: 0
forward("user@customdomain.me")
```

```
Domain settings:
DKIM selector     mailo
Tracking hostname email
```

```
SMTP credentials
username: postmaster@customdomain.me
```

I am currently switching from mailspring to thunderbird because of a mailspring bug (see [here](https://github.com/Foundry376/Mailspring/issues/1841)). In thunderbird, I tried adding an alias to my gmail account but all email sent from the alias ends up in spam because of the mismatch between sender and From field. I also tried setting up a new account with the following settings but this isn't worki

```
protocol: imap
hostname: imap.gmail.com
port: 993
username: myusername@gmail.com

protocol: smtp
hostname: smtp.mailgun.org
port: 587
username: postmaster@customdomain.me
```

but thunderbird "fails to find the settings for this email account". I can send from an alias in gmail using the mailgum smtp server and postmaster@customdomain.me username. I waas also able to do this in mailspring.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: no, I've been using gmail to send mail that requires the alias...